ORA-02437: cannot validate (FIDDLE_ZMSLRUPSPEPJBOYIFWON.PEOPLE1_PK) - primary key violateD
I am having trouble with ORA-02437: cannot validate (FIDDLE_ZMSLRUPSPEPJBOYIFWON.PEOPLE1_PK) - primary key violateD. I have two identical tables. The first table I am able to create a primary key. I then use a select as statement to create an identical table. I would think I can alter the table to create the same primary key. I am not able to do so.
I create my table.
CREATE TABLE people(
  big_id int,
  little_id int,
  name varchar(55),
  status int,
  phone varchar(55),
  primary key(big_id, little_id)
);

I add some data to my table and it does not complain.
INSERT INTO people (big_id, little_id, name, status, phone) 
  WITH names AS (
    SELECT 1001 big_id, 1 little_id, 'jOHN' name, 1 status, '214-444-1234' phone     FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 1001, 2, 'John', 1, '214-444-1234'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1002, 9, 'John', 1, '214-444-1234'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1002, 4, 'John', 1, '214-444-1234'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1003, 7, 'Mary', 0, '555-111-1234'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1003, 5, 'Mary', 0, '555-111-1234'    FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 1004, 1, 'Mary', 0, '555-111-1234'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1004, 8, 'Mary', 0, '555-111-1234'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1005, 7, 'Jeff', 0, '214-222-1234'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1005, 3, 'Jeff', 0, '214-222-1234'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1006, 2, 'Jeff', 0, '214-222-1234'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1006, 5, 'Jeff', 0, '214-222-1234'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1007, 2, 'Bill', 1, '817-333-1234'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1007, 9, 'Bill', 1, '817-333-1234'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1008, 2, 'Bill', 1, '817-333-1234'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1008, 7, 'Bill', 1, '817-333-1234'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1009, 9, 'Bob' , 1, '214-555-1234'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1009, 1, 'Bob' , 1, '214-555-1234'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1010, 5, 'Bob' , 1, '214-555-1234'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1010, 4, 'Bob' , 1, '214-555-1234'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1011, 6, 'Ruth',     1,      'Mrs'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1011, 4, 'Ruth',     1,      'Mrs'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1012, 8, 'Isabelle', 2,      'Miss'   FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1012, 5, 'Isabelle', 2,      'Miss'   FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 1013, 1, 'Justin',   3,     'Master' FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1013, 7, 'Justin',   3,     'Master' FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1014, 7, 'Jason',   3,     'Master' FROM dual UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1014, 5, 'Lisa',     4,      'Dr'     FROM dual 
  ) 
  SELECT * FROM names;

I then create another identical table.
create table people1 as (select * from people);

The tables are identical so I would think I would be able to create the same primary key. I look at this thread for ideas. It says to use exceptions so I do so. It does not explain what the next step is. I also create an exceptions table since I do not have it.
ORA-02437: cannot validate <name> - primary key violated
CREATE TABLE exceptions(
  ROW_ID varchar(55), 
  OWNER varchar(55), 
  TABLE_NAME varchar(55), 
  CONSTRAINT varchar(55)
);

ALTER TABLE people1
ADD CONSTRAINT people1_pk primary key(big_id, little_id)
exceptions into exceptions;

Another person in this post said to do this. The count is picking up same big_id and different little_id as the same. If that is the case how did I not get a primary key violation on the first table?
SELECT big_id, little_id, name, COUNT(*)
FROM people1
GROUP BY big_id, little_id, name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;

I created a dbfiddle.
https://dbfiddle.uk/HneC7VFr
edit
Is there a way show all columns like this?
SELECT *, COUNT(*)
FROM people1
GROUP BY big_id, little_id, name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;

Is there a way to do comments like this?
/* insert into people1 select * from people; */
ORA-01742: comment not terminated properly

-- insert into people1 select * from people; 
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

https://dbfiddle.uk/pTCq-sY4

You have create table people1 as (select * from people); and it shows you that it copied row data as well. And then you do insert into people1 select * from people; that adds the same rows again.

@PM77-1 thank you. Reusing fiddles and thought I removed it. If what I did was not obvious how you use the exceptions table to figure this out?

I did not use exception data itself - but the number of exceptions was telling.

@PM77-1 can you look at my edit please?

In your dbfiddle you create table people1 using:
create table people1 as (select * from people);

But then immediately insert those rows to the table again a second time:
insert into people1 select * from people;

If you don't add the duplicate rows, the PK constraint is created fine: https://dbfiddle.uk/zAaQj-HW
Edit: personally I don't find the exceptions table very helpful to explain this kind of problem. In this case it was this query that raised a red flag that there were duplicates:
SELECT big_id, little_id, name, COUNT(*)
FROM people1
GROUP BY big_id, little_id, name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;

I usually follow up a query like that by looking at the first pair of duplicates in the list just to make sure:
select * from people1 where big_id = 1001 and little_id = 1;

Second edit:
Your comments are fine actually - they're valid Oracle SQL syntax. dbfiddle just requires you to have a sql statement in each cell. It can't ONLY be a comment, or it'll give you an error. See this one: https://dbfiddle.uk/RIwLbEfJ
If you want to "show all columns" for duplicate rows, you probably want to take the duplicate query and make it a subquery or similar, e.g.
SELECT *
FROM people1 p
join (select big_id, little_id, name
      from people1
      GROUP BY big_id, little_id, name
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) p2
  on p2.big_id = p.big_id and p2.little_id = p.little_id and p2.name = p.name
order by p.big_id, p.little_id;


thank you. Reusing fiddles and thought I removed it. If what I did was not obvious how you use the exceptions table to figure this out?

@noobprogrammer1987 I updated the answer with more explanation. You followed great troubleshooting steps but I think the exceptions table ended up being a distraction.

can you look at my edit please?

@noobprogrammer1987 sure, done

I have seen the p after people1 before but what does it mean? I almost never use joins so not sure what the p2 means. Is the p2 optional or mandatory?

@noobprogrammer1987 it's a "table alias". When you join multiple tables with the same column name (like "id"), you need to use a full reference like people1.id. In this case we're joining the table to itself, so at least one of the tables needs to be called something different. In this case I called the first one p and the second one p2.
